# How do I get sub-heading in Joomla into a normal page?

Tags: joomla, title, heading

I am working with Joomla 3.0

Joomla let's you set up a heading and a sub heading in your header/banner.

I don't like how the text is layed out in the heading because it is often times not properly aligned. On different devices, the text would show up in different parts of the heading. Given this problem, I took off the sub-heading(which contained the city names where the busienss provides the service for SEO purposes), and my page ranking dropped.

Therefore I want to put the city names somewhere on the site where they carry the same SEO weight, but without having them in the actual heading/banner because of the alignment problems.

How do I get this sub title/heading SEO power in the body somewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: WHy not just make a layout override and lay it out he way you want it?

Comment: I have a custom template that I made. But the Joomla build is such that it does the heading and sub-heading for you. I want to not enter anything into the heading and sub-heading section, and maybe change something in CSS to go ahead and put those into the top of the body page for every page or something.

Comment: Have you read about how to create a layout override?  That is the method for replacing the core layouts.

Comment: I don't think it's a layout issue. If anyone knows the weight and the section of code that carries the sub-heading strings, and they know how to embed it elsewhere such as even the footer of the page on all pages that should work. I seem to not be able to find any of it.

Comment: Ok can you just paste some rendered code? Because Joomla does not have a concept of heading and subheading. It has the concept of a page heading and of a title which are rendered with h1 and h2 respectively and both of those are positioned in the layouts.  
Where exactly are you entering the data that you say are rendering as "heading" and "subheading"?

Comment: Interesting. I wouldn't mind the footer of every page displaying it. (I keep my footer constant on every page). If I put it there and style it as h1 and h2 will it serve the same purpose?

Comment: The same purpose as what? What is it that you mean by heading and subheading?

Comment: They are the things that carry heavy weight towards SEO because they label your whole site, so they must remain consistent throughout every single page.

Comment: Please, answer the question. I did not ask you what you meant, I assume you mean things with h1 and h2 tags. THe question I asked is "Where are you entering these data?" The joomla core does not have anything called "heading" or "subheading" but it does have things that produce h1 and h2 tags.  SO ...  Is this from an extensin or are you referring to the title and page heading or something else? 
But basically I'm giving up becasue I have asked you the same question multiple times and you have not answered.

Comment: If you go to templates manager, you can type in title and sub-title which is then automatically printed onto your header.

Comment: So it has nothing to do wiht individual pages, you mean you template has some parameters with those names and you don't like how they are rendered?  You can do whatever you want, but I would make a copy of the template and just move whatever is calling those parameters to a place you want them or fix the css that is making them not work the way you want.